# How to calculate distance (not displacement) between two gps cordinates

Tags: php, android, google-maps, gps, google-distancematrix-api

I have current lat and long and speed of the vehicle and wanted to get distance for the points that is close to my current position, 
but from:

> Haversine formula - R. W. Sinnott, "Virtues of the Haversine"
>   - SQL Query to get distance.

I am only getting displacement not distance. I wanted to get route distance by road (not air ;) ).
Also tried distance calculation JSON API 
[GOOGLE API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=28.46,77.08&destination=28.44,77.03&sensor=false&units=metric) but while calculation for more than 10 coordinates in loop it is taking too much time to deliver results on mobile platform by REST API.

does anybody can help me to give best results by finding distance between two gps based points.
Next: I am also looking for finding direction of the points in terms of (north-east) or degree.

Comment: Try BING API ??

Comment: If you are interested only in driving distance, why bother to even mention the Haversine stuff (which is applicable to air travel including great circle distance)?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for the [Google Distance API?](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/)... Seems to be a complete example on that site. You were looking up directions (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/...) and not the distance info ( https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json).  I have to believe the distance stuff responds quicker than detailed directions.

Comment: +1 Zipzit, i have also used [link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&destinations=40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C&key=***) to get results but for first time it is taking around 1200 msec. and then next time hit it is fine. can i only retrieve distance value ? so it might be fast to give results.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT userName, (
                6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(  " . $currentLatitude . " ) ) * COS( RADIANS(location.latitude) ) * COS( RADIANS(location.longitude) - RADIANS( " . $currentLongitude . " ) ) + 
                                SIN( RADIANS(  " . $currentLatitude . " ) ) * SIN( RADIANS(location.latitude) ) )
                                ) `distance` "
```

This calculates the distance of the point that i saved in database from the distance i provide in the $currentLatitude and $currentLongitude. It works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks @Darshan , i have used same in SQL query but it only give you displacement (not distance by road). and i am looking for distance in meter by road.